# Assertz causing "no permission to modify static procedure" error

Tags: prolog

I am trying to define initial position of the agent as direction/2:

```
direction(1, west).
```

And then define a predicate to change agent's direction:

```
turnLeft(T) :-
    TNext is T+1,
    direction(T, west), assertz(direction(TNext, north)),!,
    direction(T, south), assertz(direction(TNext, west)),!,
    direction(T, east), assertz(direction(TNext, south)),!,
    direction(T, north), assertz(direction(TNext, east)).
```

However, when I invoke i.e. `turnLeft(1)`, a following error occurs:

```
No permission to modify static procedure `direction/2'
```

I am using online SWISH IDE, does it have anything to do with it or does the problem lie in something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates are static by default. To make a predicate dynamic, i.e. to allow its definition to change at runtime by asserting and retracting clauses for it, you need to use the standard `dynamic/1` predicate directive.

Add at the top of the file the directive:

```
:- dynamic(direction/2).
```